# Change text 'Add an item' in tree view odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How in custom module change text 'Add an item' to 'Add new row"?

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hello Pointer,**

## Using odoo 8

Try this below code,

> your_module_name/view/custome_file_include.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <template id="assets_backend" name="account assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">

                <!-- Include External/Custom/Own JS File. And Order Maintain.  -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module_name/static/src/js/custome_file_include.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module_name/static/src/js/custome_view_form.js"></script>

            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

> your_module_name/src/js/custome_file_include.js

```
openerp.fm_sale_order_ext_ept = function(instance) {
    change_tree_view_add_item_name(instance);
}
```

> your_module_name/src/js/custome_view_form.js

```
function change_tree_view_add_item_name(instance) {


    instance.web.form.AddAnItemList.include({
        pad_table_to: function (count) {
            if (!this.view.is_action_enabled('create') || this.is_readonly()) {
                this._super(count);
                return;
            }

            this._super(count > 0 ? count - 1 : 0);

            var self = this;
            var columns = _(this.columns).filter(function (column) {
                return column.invisible !== '1';
            }).length;
            if (this.options.selectable) { columns++; }
            if (this.options.deletable) { columns++; }

            var $cell = $('<td>', {
                colspan: columns,
                'class': this._add_row_class || ''
            }).html(
                $('<a>', {href: '#'}).text(_t("Add new row"))
                    .mousedown(function () {
                        // FIXME: needs to be an official API somehow
                        if (self.view.editor.is_editing()) {
                            self.view.__ignore_blur = true;
                        }
                    })
                    .click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        // FIXME: there should also be an API for that one
                        if (self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout) {
                            clearTimeout(self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout);
                            self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout = false;
                        }
                        self.view.ensure_saved().done(function () {
                            self.view.do_add_record();
                        });
                    }));

            var $padding = this.$current.find('tr:not([data-id]):first');
            var $newrow = $('<tr>').append($cell);
            if ($padding.length) {
                $padding.replaceWith($newrow);
            } else {
                this.$current.replaceWith($newrow)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

## Using odoo9

First we create new module and given below is file structure of new module.

```
Module_Name
    static
            src
                js
                    File_Name.js
    views
            File_Name.xml
    __openerp__.py
```

> Module_Name->views->File_Name.xml
>   Now we add the custome js in base odoo 9 module so we are create xml file and inherit base file and add our custome js,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>

            <template id="assets_backend" name="account assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">

                <!-- Include External/Custom/Own JS File. And Order Maintain.  -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/Module_Name/static/src/js/File_Name.js"></script>

            </xpath>
        </template>
        </data>
    </openerp>
```

> Module_Name->static->src->js->File_Name.js
>   Now we are inherit base form_relation_widget.js js and modify this method,

```
odoo.define('Module_Name.File_Name', function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView');

    var _t = core._t;
    var _lt = core._lt;

    // Include "web.form_relational"
    var form_relational = require('web.form_relational');

    // Include X2ManyList Functionality and Modify X2ManyList Functionality
    var form_relational = form_relational.X2ManyList.include({
        pad_table_to: function (count) {
            if (!this.view.is_action_enabled('create') || this.view.x2m.get('effective_readonly')) {
                this._super(count);
                return;
            }

            this._super(count > 0 ? count - 1 : 0);

            var self = this;
            var columns = _(this.columns).filter(function (column) {
                return column.invisible !== '1';
            }).length;
            if (this.options.selectable) { columns++; }
            if (this.options.deletable) { columns++; }

            var $cell = $('<td>', {
                colspan: columns,
                'class': 'oe_form_field_x2many_list_row_add'
            }).append(
                $('<a>', {href: '#'}).text(_t("Add new row"))
                    .click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        // FIXME: there should also be an API for that one
                        if (self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout) {
                            clearTimeout(self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout);
                            self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout = false;
                        }
                        self.view.save_edition().done(function () {
                            self.view.do_add_record();
                        });
                    }));

            var $padding = this.$current.find('tr:not([data-id]):first');
            var $newrow = $('<tr>').append($cell);
            if ($padding.length) {
                $padding.replaceWith($newrow);
            } else {
                this.$current.replaceWith($newrow);
            }
        },
    });

});
```

> Module_Name->**openerp**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Part of Odoo. See LICENSE file for full copyright and licensing details.

{
    'name': 'Module Name',
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': '',
    'sequence': 1,
    'summary': '',
    'description': """ Give the Description of Module """,
    'website': '',
    'depends': ['web'],
    'data': [
        'views/File_Name.xml'
    ],
    'demo': [],
    'css': [],
    'js' : [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
}
```

> odoo_v9->web->static->src->js->views->form_relation_widget.js

Add X2ManyList : X2ManyList this line in base js (odoo9 module) form_relation_widget.js

```
return {
    FieldMany2ManyTags: FieldMany2ManyTags,
    AbstractManyField: AbstractManyField,
    X2ManyList : X2ManyList,  ////Add this line in this file
};
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.

Comment: Tnx for help, I'm copy your code but text is not changed!

Comment: This module create in odoo 8. And i sucefully run this

Comment: Ok i will create in odoo 9 after update my question as soon as...Thanx

Answer (score 1):

An option could be that you enter on debug mode.

Then, go to **Configuration** -> **Application Terms** -> **Synchronize Terms**. In the dropdown Language, select English and wait until finish.

Go to **Translated Terms**, in the search field write "Add an item" and replace the text that is in **Translation Value** column.

It's worth say, this change will stored in the DB and all one2many relations will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

This string is provided by [JavaScript code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9494161e230e05fd918ac46626e5ed3d8b85d7ca/addons/web/static/src/js/views/form_relational_widgets.js#L1027). So you have to extend the js widget to change the name.